# How can I rotate a given matrix by one element clockwise in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I am writing a short program that rotates a given NxN matrix the following way:

```
┌     ┐    ┌     ┐ 
|1 2 3|    |4 1 2| 
|4 5 6| -> |7 5 3| 
|7 8 9|    |8 9 6|   
└     ┘    └     ┘
```

```js
var a = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
    document.write(a[i][j]);
  }
  document.write('<br>');
};
```

I got the loop sorted and the array but I cannot figure out how to rotate it clockwise. 
It is really becoming a headache.

All help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Stay away from `document.write` [for a number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/215552).

Comment: What kind of rotation is this?

Comment: its a homework given from a trainee internship interview...I'm relatively new in programming..and this seems totally out of my league but I will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move each side and use an offset for the rings.

This approach takes four loops, one for every side of the matrix and stores previously the value of the top left position of each ring.

Then all item are moved and the the item of all ther sides are moved as well. Finally, at the last loop, the saved item is move to a new position.

Example of the algorithm:

```
2D Array  1  2  3  4  5
          6  7  8  9 10
         11 12 13 14 15
         16 17 18 19 20
         21 22 23 24 25
------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
         take value for   1st loop         2nd loop         3rd loop         4th loop
         insert in 4th    left side up     bottom left      right down       top right
------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
Ring 0  [ 1] 2  3  4  5    6  .  .  .  .    .  .  .  .  .    .  .  .  .  .    .[ 1] 2  3  4
          6  .  .  . 10   11           .    .           .    .           5    .           .
         11  .  .  . 15   16           .    .           .    .          10    .           .
         16  .  .  . 20   21           .    .           .    .          15    .           .
         21 22 23 24 25    .  .  .  .  .   22 23 24 25  .    .  .  .  . 20    .  .  .  .  .

Ring 1    .  .  .  .  .                                                      
          .[ 7] 8  9  .      12  .  .          .  .  .          .  .  .          .[ 7] 8
          . 12  . 14  .      17     .          .     .          .     9          .     .
          . 17 18 19  .       .  .  .         18 19  .          .  . 14          .  .  .
          .  .  .  .  .
------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
Result    6  1  2  3  4
         11 12  7  8  5
         16 17 13  9 10
         21 18 19 14 15
         22 23 24 25 20
```

```js
function rotate(array) {

    function rotateRing(offset) {
        var i = offset,
            j = offset,
            l = array.length - offset,
            last = array[i][j];

        for (; i + 1 < l; i++) array[i][j] = array[i + 1][j];
        for (; j + 1 < l; j++) array[i][j] = array[i][j + 1];
        for (; i > offset; i--) array[i][j] = array[i - 1][j];
        for (; j > offset; j--) array[i][j] = j - 1 === offset ? last : array[i][j - 1];
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = array.length >> 1; i < l; i++) rotateRing(i);
    return array;
}

function print(array) {
    array.forEach(a => console.log(...a.map(v => v.toString().padStart(2))));
    console.log('');
}

var array3 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    array4 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]],
    array5 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]];

print(array3);
rotate(array3);
print(array3);

print(array4);
rotate(array4);
print(array4);

print(array5);
rotate(array5);
print(array5);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this answer if fantastic, but I did not study this yet. is there possibly any way to simplify it?

Comment: you could delete the ouput parts, but it stays as it it, because you need a loop for each side to move and the same for each ring in the matrix. but if you may have a shorter approach, i am open.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say its the algorithmic approach but yeah it's quite easy to understand the code.

```js
var btn5Element = document.getElementById("btn5")

let arrElement = ["1","2","3","6","9","8","7","4"]
                // 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 --array
                // 0   1   2   5   8   7   6   3 -- node

const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('button');
btn5Element.addEventListener("click", myRotateFunction);

function myRotateFunction(){
    let temp = arrElement.pop()
    arrElement.unshift(temp)
    nodeList[0].innerHTML = arrElement[0]
    nodeList[1].innerHTML = arrElement[1]
    nodeList[2].innerHTML = arrElement[2]
    
    nodeList[3].innerHTML = arrElement[7]
    //
    nodeList[5].innerHTML = arrElement[3]
    
    nodeList[6].innerHTML = arrElement[6]
    nodeList[7].innerHTML = arrElement[5]
    nodeList[8].innerHTML = arrElement[4]
    
}
```

```css
#btns{
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
}

#btns button{
    position : relative;
    width : 30%;
    height : 48px;
    font-size : 24px
    
}
```

```html
<!-- Enter your HTML code here -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttonsGrid.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Buttons Grid</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='btns'>
        <button id='btn1'>1</button>
        <button id='btn2'>2</button>
        <button id='btn3'>3</button>
        <br>
        <button id='btn4'>4</button>
        <button id='btn5'>5</button>
        <button id='btn6'>6</button>
        <br>
        <button id='btn7'>7</button>
        <button id='btn8'>8</button>
        <button id='btn9'>9</button>

    </div>
    <script src="buttonsGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```